# Incrementing 1 variable with zero at the left doesn't return the correct result

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm doing a bat file to automate some stuff and it uses both future and a target past date to do stuff. It gets the date from the system in MM/DD/YYYY format.

The problem is the next one: When I have the day "09" (for example) and I increment that number (to obtain tomorrow's date), the result is "1" not "10"

For the sake of simplicity, I created a little bat just with the problematic area and it still happens. This is the code (the simplified one):

```
set day=09
set /a day=day+1 (or set /a day+=1)
echo %day%
pause
```

If I put "9" instead of "09", it will return 10, but it has to work with 2 digit day (from 01 to 31).

What I'm missing? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Numbers with leading zeros are treated as octal numbers -- according to the help text of `set /?`:

> Numeric values are decimal numbers, unless prefixed by 0x for hexadecimal numbers, and 0 for octal numbers. So 0x12 is the same as 18 is the same as 022. Please note that the octal notation can be confusing: 08 and 09 are not valid numbers because 8 and 9 are not valid octal digits.

`08` and `09`, for instance, are considered as invalid numbers, so they are treated like strings, which are substituted by `0` for arithmetic operations. Therefore, `set /A` returns an unexpected result.

You can remove leading zeros with the following code snippet, independent from the total number of digits, supposing the number is provided by the variable `NUM` (for instance, `set "NUM=0123"`):

```
for /F "tokens=* delims=0" %%N in ("%NUM%") do set "NUM=%%N"
set /A NUM+=0 & rem // (this is to avoid an empty variable if `NUM` consisted of `0` only)
```

**Note:**
The `if` command (with command extensions enabled) treats purely numeric comparison expressions in the same manner in case a comparison operator other than `==` is used (`EQU`, etc.).

Comment: Thanks a lot. The code didn't worked but I found other option: SET /a variabletotrim = 1%variabletotrim%-(11%variabletotrim%-1%variabletotrim%)/10

Comment: Sorry, I used two different variable names in the code (`NUM` and `NUMBER`), but I corrected that now (see my edit); an alternative method would be: `set /A VAR=1%VAR%+1-100`, so `VAR` becomes incremented; this works *only* if `VAR` contains a number consisting of *exactly two digits*! to make the result to consist of two digits after incrementing, do: `set "VAR=0%VAR%"` and `set "VAR=%VAR:~-2%`

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to force the two digit number to be interpreted as decimal while adding 1 to it is to prefix it with a `1` character and then subtract 99:

```
set /a day=1%day% - 99
```

Since prefixing a two digit number with a 1 is the same adding 100 to it, subtracting 99 then results in the number being incremented by 1.

Comment: Thanks for the help!